# Multiple bindings on jQuery sortable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have three lists and am using the jQuery sortable plugin to allow me to re-order within each list and then drag and drop between lists.

When I move an item between lists then my ajax request is triggered:

```
$( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection().bind('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "admin.php?action=change_route_assignment&routeID="+this.id+"&id="+ui.item[0].id,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("change saved");
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });

});
```

I would also like to trigger the request if I re-order items within the same list. I think the binding for this is sortchange.

How do I change my code so it triggers for both sortreceive and sortchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this actually appears to be easy. I just listed both events separated with a space ...

```
$( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection().bind('sortreceive sortchange', function(event, ui) {
```